# Should we instantiate a map object in Java with explicit type?

Tags: type-inference

I was told by a friend that in practice/industry we should write:

```
Map<Class1, Class2> map = new HashMap<>();
```

instead of

```
Map<Class1, Class2> map = new HashMap<Class1, Class2>();
```

Is there any specific reason for this coding style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the compiler will understand `HashMap<>` is a `HashMap<Class1, Class2>` and you `don't` need to `repeat your self`. Later if you want to change `Class1, Class2` you will only need to change in a single place.

It's the same like some modern language like C#, Swift, Kotlin start to write `var a = 5` instead of `int a = 5`

Comment: That's type inference